# Reg Expression and Optional match Groups

Tags: regex

I am running into an issue where i have strings which have a possibly 2 or 4 match groups

the text for the 2 looks like this

```
<FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=2>1260 CORONA POINTE STE 120<br/>CORONA, CA  92879<br/><br/></font></td></tr>
```

the 4 match groups

```
<FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=2>4010 BARRANCA PKWY STE 120<br/>IRVINE, CA  92604<br/><A HREF = "pplinfo.asp?License_id=01241755">01241755</A> Oldhouse, Charles  - Branch/Division Manager<br><br/><br/></font>
```

Here is the regular expression i use to match the 4

```
<FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=2>(.*?)<br\/>(.*?)<br\/>.*License_id=(\d*).*<\/A>(.*?)<br>
```

is there a way to make this expression also match the string which has only 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question looks awful familiar.

Here you go

`<FONT[ ]FACE="Arial,Helvetica"[ ]size=2>(.*?)<br/>(.*?)<br/>(?:.*License_id=(\d*)(?:.*</A>(.*?)<br>)?)?`

https://regex101.com/r/O8Ctn2/1

Formatted

```
 <FONT [ ] FACE="Arial,Helvetica" [ ] size=2>
 ( .*? )                       # (1)
 <br/>
 ( .*? )                       # (2)
 <br/> 
 (?:
      .* License_id=
      ( \d* )                       # (3)
      (?:
           .* </A>
           ( .*? )                       # (4)
           <br>
      )?
 )?
```